# How to host nodejs application with sockect.io

Tags: node.js, database, web-hosting

I have build an chat application using nodejs with mysql database. I have developed on my windows system and it works fine.

Now I want to make it live on a server to check its real time performance, As a beginner I don't know which server hosting should I choose to develop nodejs application, so someone please suggest me a hosting for nodejs application?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something relatively easy to test on, Heroku will provide you with a free instance.

I can also recommend Azure over Amazon for a simple nodejs based app. The main reason is that Azure has a very simplified interface for deploying node apps after a little bit of minor setup. Amazon offers similar capabilities, but the last time I looked at them they aren't quite as simple to get up and running. Again, they're competitive in cost and reliability, this is just a subjective opinion on what I think will be easier for a dev to get up and running without prior experience.

Comment: My application uses a database, so is it possible to set there?

Comment: Sure, they have a sql database solution. Its inexpensive.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dokku, an open source solution for a Heroku like PaaS. Either of those are great for doing git style deployments. Heroku has better documentation, and doesn't require your own server so I would start with them.

https://www.heroku.com 
http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku